# Implementing Batch Execution of Makefile Command Operations Using TCL Scripts or SHELL Scripts

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
// The Tcl file code is as following[it's name is test.tcl]:
make run_test TESTNAME = test1.sv
make run_test TESTNAME = test2.sv
make run_test TESTNAME = test3.sv
make run_test TESTNAME = test4.sv
make run_test TESTNAME = test5.sv
make run_test TESTNAME = test6.sv
```

I implement it in the linux ternimal
command: ./test.tcl
resoult:

```
make: *** empty variable name. Stop
make: *** empty variable name. Stop
make: *** empty variable name. Stop
make: *** empty variable name. Stop
make: *** empty variable name. Stop
make: *** empty variable name. Stop
```

I don't know why it is this resoult, I specifically execute a make command on the console to run normally (make run_test TESTNAME = test1.sv); and my colleague use the same way can run ....

Implementing Batch Execution of Makefile Command Operations Using TCL Scripts or SHELL Scripts

Comment: Try `TESTNAME=test1.sv` (no spaces).

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't expect there to be a problem with this place, just due to the separation of spaces

Comment: Different from natural languages computer language are usually very strict with the syntax. When trying to adapt others' code to your needs you'd better avoid uselessly adding or removing parts, even spaces, if you don't know what the effects could be. And if you encounter errors in your code that did not happen with the original code, try to find the differences. All differences, even spaces.

Comment: The file named test.tcl does not contain Tcl code.  I'm guessing it just gets run by the shell.  So the [Tcl] tag seems inappropriate here.